# Try change one ListView element Bug

Tags: android, listview, click

Im trying to change a ImageView from a ListView when I click on it.
My method how I try it looks like this :

```
private void updateEQAnimation(int index){
    View v = LV_songView.getChildAt(index -LV_songView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
        return;

    ImageView EQ_ANIM = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView_eq_animation);
    EQ_ANIM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

this is called in my `onItemClickListener` of my ListView like this :

```
updateEQAnimation(position);
```

**Now my Problem:**

When I scroll up or down somehow the ImageView of other ListView elements changes also.But I actually want to change only **one**.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is add a public method in your list adapter how? i will describe.

1. First create your own object that you want to show in list view.

   ```
   public class YourObject {

   private int id;
   private int avatar;
   private String name;

   public YourObject(int id, int avatar, String name) {
       this.id = id;
       this.avatar = avatar;
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getAvatar() {
       return avatar;
   }

   public void setAvatar(int avatar) {
       this.avatar = avatar;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return new Gson().toJson(this);
   }}
   ```
2. Make an adapter like below :

   public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   ```
   private AppCompatActivity ctx;
   private LayoutInflater li;
   private LinkedHashMap<Integer, YourObject> items;

   public YourAdapter(AppCompatActivity ctx, LinkedHashMap<Integer, YourObject> items) {
       this.ctx = ctx;
       this.items = items;
       this.li = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return items.size();
   }

   @Override
   public YourObject getItem(int position) {
       List<YourObject> lst = new ArrayList<>(items.values());
       return lst.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.lst_item_your_view, null);
       ImageView avatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
       CustomTextView name = (CustomTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

       name.setText(getItem(position).getName());

       avatar.setImageResource(getItem(position).getAvatar());

       return convertView;
   }

   public void refresh(final YourObject yourObject) {
               items.remove(yourObject.getId());
               items.put(yourObject.getId(), yourObject);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

   }
3. Now in your activity you can change it every where like below:

   YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(ctx , items);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
   YourObject your object = new YourObject(id ,     R.drawable.other_icon,"name");
   adapter.refresh(yourObject);

Comment: What really makes the effect that this bug effect is cleared ?

Comment: In android listview object store just some element of your adapter in memory (related to your screen size and element count that can shown in listview and just a little more). so you should know you must save your objects state in your list and change it when you want